# Create 1-click Telegram invite links using the API

Tags: telegram

I have this private telegram channel which I'll charge for access (premium content). I just have found that now you can create a temporary invite link that expires by time or by number of clicks (see attachment). This would be great to automate my payment process as I could generate a unique link for each new customer that makes a payment, so they can only use once, and won't be able to share to others.

Any ideas on how to generate this links using the API? This feature must be really new as I haven't found anything in the documentation.

Many thanks in advance,
Ed

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phCbQ.png)

Answer (score 6):

1. Open [API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)
2. Press CTRL+F (or CMD+F on Mac)
3. Type `link`, press Enter and RTM

Example:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#createchatinvitelink

Also look at the `member_limit` param for this method.

Comment: Thank you, will have a look!

Answer (score 1):

See the php function for this problem:

```
function createChatInviteLink($apiToken, $chat_id){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify('+12 month');
    $data = array(
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'member_limit' => 1,
            'expire_date' => $date->getTimestamp()
        );
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/createChatInviteLink";

    //  open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    //  set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //  number of POST vars
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    //  POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    //  To display result of curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //  execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //  close connection
    curl_close($ch);    
    return $result;
}
```